# How to sign in an active user in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, sql, authentication, laravel-5

I have a users table which holds every detail of the user including a field called 'isActive' which is a Boolean.

I want to log in the user if the 'isActive = 1' and also i want to redirect the user back to the login page if the 'isActive = 0'.

My code is below:

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request) 

{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
  ]);

  if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
     return redirect()->route('home');
  }
}
```

The code above allows me to sign normally. With or without the isActive field being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication),

> If you wish, you also may add extra conditions to the authentication
>   query in addition to the user's e-mail OR username and password. For
>   example, we may verify that user is marked as "**active**":

In your case, you just need to add **'isActive' => 1** in array.

Your code should be:-

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password'],'isActive' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
else{
   // The user is Inactive, suspended, or not exists.
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Comment: I have on more question. For example, my user is logged in and then I decide to deactivate them.

Comment: I want to log them out when they press any link

Comment: I created a Middleware class with a function that checks if the Auth::user is active //do something else Auth::logout and redirect to login page.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the extra field into the `attempt` method

```
if(Auth::attempt([
    'username' => $request['username'], 
    'password' => $request['password'],
    'isActive' => 1,
    ])
) 
{
   return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

This is all covered [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users).

Comment: @edmond could you perhaps upvote and/or accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you guys are getting your code from as mine is massively different. Are you guys upgrading to 5.2 or installing it through a fresh install of 5.2? Here's what I have in my login method:

```
    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }
```

I didn't want to override the remember functionality, so I use this way:

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $request = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
    $request['active'] = true;
    return $request;
}
```

Basically add `$request['active'] = true;` to the getCredential method in your `App/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.